# How to retrieve data from a table in a database and print it in a table in a GUI form in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I  have a database with tables in it which contains information. I would like to retrieve data from the table which is on the database to the table which I have made on a GUI form. I have tried retrieving the data using `system.out.print` method and I get results, meaning the database connection works and recognizes the table. Only problem is I do not know how to that for tables in the code. Please keep in mind that the GUI I made, the code was generated automatically so I do not have 100% access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to the database seems to be correct, however, you cannot set your table to contain the values you need. If the diagnosis is correct, then below you will find useful information:

I do not know what are you using for tables, I will assume you are using JTable, but if you use something else, only technical details should change as the thought process should remain intact.

To get general knowledge, please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.